# drawing a circle UIButton performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am currently doing it the following:

```
  self.userProfileButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.userProfileButton.layer.borderWidth=1.5f;
    self.userProfileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
```

size of the button is 50, so this makes it as a perfect circle. However, when I profile this using instrument, it seems that it's dropping the FPS down a bit. Any other idea on how to do this performance wise?

Comment: Use a custom button with a circular image instead?

Comment: the image I got from backend is a square.. if that's the case I'd have to crop it on my end to be a circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rasterize it!

```
self.userProfileButton.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
//For retina screens:
self.userProfileButton.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: can you explain how rasterizing it would speed it up?

Comment: @adit it causes the CALayer to create an image of the button with all CALayer properties (such as the corner radius) applied prior to compositing it; otherwise the main content of the view is cached but the layer properties are applied (and reapplied, ad nauseam) while compositing.

Comment: @adit when you rasterize the layer, the layer is flatten so all modifications (shadows, corner radius, etc...) is applied indefinitely to the layer. Without rasterization, layer modifications are applied in every frame which is why it slowed down your app.

Comment: @adit where are you putting the rasterization code? Could you upload the entire class?

Comment: So this UIButton is inside a UICollectionViewCell class and I am putting it in the awakeFromNib. The whole class is too big to upload it here. Am I putting it at the wrong place?